# Input Unicode string in String.Format() method;

Tags: c#, string, unicode, format

I want to input Unicode string in String.Format() method.

**This is my code:**

```
string filename = String.Format("Това трябва да е уникод {0}_{1}.doc", wayBillNum, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

//File name for the exported word document
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
```

How to do this?

Comment: so, whats a problem?

Comment: Well, what happens at the moment? In particular, have you looked at `filename` in the debugger to see if it has the right value? My suspicion is that this is more likely to be a matter of encoding headers than `string.Format` being broken....

Comment: Strings in C# are always Unicode. The question as such is a bit nonsensical. Are you instead asking how to provide a Unicode file name for the `Content-Disposition` header? This has nothing to do with C# at all in that case.